# Sizzle's Javascript regex for CLASS?

Tags: javascript, regex, sizzle

I've looked at Prototype.js code and I saw there ( at the Sizzle part) :

[image]

My question is about that line :

`CLASS: /\.((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF\-]|\\.)+)/,`

the `\.` is for dot , 
next is (uncaptured group with : words, range and `-`) OR (`\.`). *( actually it says `\\.` but the first one is just for escaping so it's `\.`)*.

Huh ?

What's `\.` ?

*I did test `/\.((?:[\w\u00c0-\uFFFF\-]|\\.)+)/.test('.aa\.')` and it returns `true`*.

But what is `.aa\.` ? obviously the class is `.aa` but if `\` is a valid char , why it isn't at the `[..]` section ?

What am I missing ?

Comment: Imagine you have a class in your HTML that's `foo.bar`. That is a valid single class in HTML, but it messes up the CSS style selectors because of the `.`. So to use a selector to select it, it needs to look like `".foo\.bar"`. *DEMO:* http://jsfiddle.net/PGmEr/

Comment: It's hard to say [apparently Sizzle has completely refactored this code](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js). It *looks* like they were trying to implement some sort of class navigation like .classA\.class1 but I can't really tell without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: @BlueSkies why not `".foo\.bar"`

Comment: @blesh Prototype latest ver uses it. So I guess there's meanning

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That's what I have. I had a typo at first if you're referring to the `".foo\\.bar"` that I originally had. I thought the backslash would be removed, so I escaped it at first. But in JS string literal, you would need `".foo\\.bar"` in order to create the characters `.foo\.bar`. See the demo I posted above.

Comment: @BlueSkies if you have a class named "foo.bar", you're doing something wrong. [CSS scanners shouldn't even recognize that](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner). I suppose if you're breaking the rules to use the class via JavaScript only that's legit. I guess what I'm saying is, I'm not sure you're right only because it sounds too crazy. lol

Comment: @blesh: Yeah, all I'm saying is that it's valid in the HTML spec for `class` attributes to include a `.` character. The CSS Selectors API spec is separate. The implementations created an escape sequence to resolve the `.` conflict.

Comment: @BlueSkies:  "it's valid in the HTML spec for class attributes to include a . character." where does it say that? Best I can find I already linked above, which pretty specifically says '.' are not allowed.

Comment: @blesh: That's a CSS specification. I'm talking about HTML class attributes. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#adef-class That said... implementations often implement additions to specified behaviors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\\.` matches a **literal backslash**, followed by any character (the dot is *not* escaped).

From http://Sizzlejs.com/:

> Escaped selector support #id\:value

It is used to match classes like `a\~b`, and it is actually repeated in most selectors on your screenshots. It is common usually when you have dots or brackets in names or classes.

As for your test:

- In JavaScript, "invalid" escape sequences are **ignored**. `"\." === "."`, and your test is the same as `.test('.aa.')`.
- `.test` allows partial matching - `/\w+/.test("a!") === true` - it doesn't mean the last dot was actually matched.

Comment: Running `$(".subheader")` here at SO console does show me the same element as `$("\.subheader")`....You're right

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Just write `"\." === "."` :-)

Comment: kobi - so why they didnt add it to the [] part?

Comment: +1 Wow. There should be a note next to that like "don't ever use this feature though"

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Adding it to `[]` (character set) would be wrong - it would allow `abc\`, which would be a mistake. More importantly, you want **any character** immediately after the backslash, a character set can't do that.